# How to Restrict Django GenericRelation to One Related Object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

The code below (from Django [contenttype docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)) permits multiple related objects (i.e. 'tags'). Is it possible to restrict this to one related object (i.e. 'tag')? And, if so, how?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    tags = GenericRelation(TaggedItem)
```

Comment: Use [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) which is described in the same link you refer to?

Comment: `GenericForeignKey` allows your model to effectively tie itself to any other model class, whereas `ForeignKey` will be in relation with one Model and only one, the related_name of that `ForeignKey` will have the same behavior as `GenericRelation`, except it restricts to One Object